# Tkinter not imported in Python to executable conversion

Tags: python, tkinter, nuitka

I am trying to convert Python code (which uses Tkinter) to executable with Nuitka but it is giving following error:

```
$ nuitka --recurse-all srcfile.py --exe
Nuitka:WARNING:srcfile.py:3: Cannot find 'tkinter.ttk' as relative or absolute import.
```

The exe file is created and it runs but stops with error:

```
File "/home/abcd/srcfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I am working on Debian Stable Linux. Where is the problem and how can this be solved?

Comment: Probably because tkinter is not python. It's written in tcl.

Comment: Is your `nuitka` installed for Python 2? `tkinter` is named `Tkinter` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuitka` is not a standalone tool but a Python module. As such, it belongs to a Python installation and uses the corresponding interpreter's facilities and library to scan the code and such.

E.g. if your copy happens to belong to a Python 2 installation, it will scan that Python 2's standard library, and Tkinter is named `Tkinter` in Python 2.

So, you need to install `nuitka` for the same Python environment as what your program is supposed to use.

Comment: Just to be clear, nuitka converts all modules to machine code or does it put together all bytecode files?

Comment: @mso http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html: _"It translates the Python into a C level program that then uses libpython and a few C files of its own to execute in the same way as CPython does."_ So I guess it converts Python code to equivalent C code that uses Python C API (roughly the same as Cython does). From what I read in the utility help, it generates intermediate C files that you can see.